# YouTubePlayer isn't playing a video

Tags: android-youtube-api

I used YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to play a YouTube video, but it plays the video for 2 or 3 second and stops automatically. I can't find what's wrong.

Below is my code for fragment translation

```
    mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
            mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(
                    "key",
                    mListnnerYouTube);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_youtube_player,
                    mYoutubePlayerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and my onInitializationSuccess

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    activeplayer = player;
    activeplayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    if (!wasRestored) {
        // player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        player.loadVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    }
```

I used YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in fragment

error message

> YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator{420b9758 V.ED.... ......I. 0,412-720,465 #7f0a005c app:id/indicator}. The view is inside the YouTubePlayerView, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 412, right: 0, bottom: 0..

Comment: Does the error message not say exactly what's going on??

Comment: It was added after my answer. Check the time, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're most likely displaying something on top of the player view**, which is forbidden by the YouTube SDK.

Check the logs, you should see a warning from the YouTube SDK that specifies why the video playback has been stopped. If a `View` is covering part of the player, the log will specify its ID and its position on the screen.

Comment: Anytime :) Could you please update your question by adding the log message that indicated this problem?